# jquery tabs cannot get rid of "+" icon in the formatting

Tags: jquery, tabs, icons

I am using jquery tabs and a custom jquery ui, however for some reason a "+" sign always appear on top of each tab, does anone know why and how to get rid of it?

[image]

I did not add any icon in the css, I only changed the background and some more.
Here's the css part for the tabs:

```
    .ui-tabs { position: relative; padding: .2em; zoom: 1; } /* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { margin: 0; padding: .2em .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; top: 0; margin: 1px .2em 0 0; text-align:center; width: 110px; border-bottom: 0;
                           padding: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a{color:#A7A88A}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { margin-bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px; background:green}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading a { cursor: text; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a { cursor: pointer; } /* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block; border-width: 0; padding: 1em 1.4em; background: none; }
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
}


.ui-tabs-nav li img {

display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto

}


#mytabs{
    padding: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-width: 0px;
}
#mytabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    padding-left: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#mytabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    background: url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f5f3e5_1x100.png) repeat-x scroll 50% top #f5f3e5;
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can we have a look at the HTML?

Comment: Please check the page at the address: http://nwscomps.com/test/sito/tendaggi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's coming from the:

```
.art-postcontent ul > li:before
{
   content:url('images/postbullets.png');
   ...
}
```

on line 3950, and

```
.art-post ul > li::before {
    content: url('images/postbullets.png');
    ...
}
```

on line 3938. You can remove those two content properties in your css, and the + sign should disappear.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. It seems like it was not related with jquery tabs then...

Comment: glad it worked :) feel free to mark it as an answer if no other problems persist.